# Article, can you help me with more examples

Tags: articles

If I want to talk about things that are the same, which articles should I use?

Eg1: A school has the same uniforms (only size is different) for boy students

Do I say:

> Daily, a boy student wears the shirt with the black jean...

or

> Daily, a boy student wears a shirt with a black jean...

Eg2: A shop sells bags (all bags are the same)

If I come the shop, and want to buy only 1 bag, do I say:

> I want to buy a bag

or

> I want to buy the bag

If I want to buy 2+ bags, do I say:

> I want to buy bags

or

> I want to buy the bags

or no article?

Comment: I prefer the  e.g. The black pants and the white shirt are the boys' daily uniform. while jeans are usually denim cotton and less classy.  and b) 3 bags please.

Comment: **eg** does not literally mean *example* and you can't use it wherever you would say *example*, like "Give me more eg."  *e.g.* stands for the Latin phrase *exempli gratia* and means something like "Here is an example."

Comment: Please note that if you are referring to yourself, the **"I"** must always be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a hard question.

Let’s start with your second example. In context, all the bags are of the same type. So, if someone were to ask you what type of bag the shop sells, you may answer

> The type of bag sold there is large and made of blue canvas

or

> The bags sold there are large and made of blue canvas

But you may also say

> The bag sold there is large and made of blue canvas

In context, the third version does not mean that the store has only a single bag to sell, but is just a shortened form of the first version with [type of] left out. This omission of [type of] is common where context makes clear that talking about a single item makes no sense.

Omissions like the one mentioned in the previous paragraph are called ellipses and must be very confusing to learners.

Now, let’s move on to your first example. The major problem with that sentence is that we don’t know the **exact** verbal context. Here is a likely way to convey the information desired.

> The boy students wear a uniform consisting of a white shirt and black jeans.

The word “uniform” already conveys the idea of similarity, and we now use the indefinite article to indicate that each boy wears a different exemplar of the shirt and trousers appropriate to that uniform.

Answer (score 0):

All of those are correct, but have different meanings.

When you use "the", it means the specific one, like "the shirt" means "the shirt that's part of the uniform". When you don't use "the", it just means a shirt.

> Daily, a boy student wears the shirt with the black jeans...

This means, every day, a boy student wears a shirt and some black jeans *that are part of the school uniform*.

> Daily, a boy student wears a shirt with black jeans...

But this one means every day, a boy student wears a shirt and some black jeans, *without specifying that they're part of the school uniform*.

The same applies to the bags.

> I want to buy a bag

This means a bag, *without mentioning that there's only one type of bag*.

> I want to buy the bag

This means a bag, and I know that there's only one type of bag.

For plural:

> I want to buy bags
> or
> I want to buy **some** bags

Here, you don't mention that there's only one type.

> I want to buy the bags

Here, you mention that there's only one type.

Comment: Thank you very much